# Get the ID of a field widget in a formset

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to customize the layout of forms in a formset (that is, I don't want to use .as_table() or .as_p() and the like). I'm trying to get the name of a form field for use in its label's `for` attribute, but I'm not sure how to go about it. I'm hoping that I won't need to construct a new name/ID for the field from scratch. Here's an example of what I'm working with right now:

```
{% for form in formset.forms %}
<!-- The field for the "path" form field -->
<label for="{{what do I put here?}}">{{form.fields.path.label}}:</label><input type="text" id="{{django creates this one; do I have to do my own with the for loop counter or something?}}" name="{{probably the same as id}}" />
{% endfor %}
```

Is there any sort of "create ID for formset field" sort of method?

Answer (score 6):

This is likely what you want.

```
for="{{ form.your_field.html_name }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you want to use the form element's *id*, instead of *name*.

I tried Django 1.3 Alpha-1 and the following worked:

```
{% for form in formset.forms %}
    <label for="{{ form.my_field.auto_id }}">{{ form.my_field.label }}</label>
    {{ form.my_field }}
{% endfor %}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Claims that that's an invalid name (Django 1.3 alpha 1).

Also, wouldn't that output a <label> tag? What if I want to, say, add classes to the label?

Comment: I haven't tried Django 1.3 alpha 1, and yes it would output a label tag, which you could then surround with a <div class="your-class">. This would allow you to control the style as well, but I admit its a work-around. I'm curious to see if this is changed behavior in Django 1.3 alpha 1. If I find anything else, I'll be sure to share it here :)