# How to add label ID in Django form 

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-forms

I am using Django form for inputs. However, I would like to custom it a little bit. For example the following Django code will be translated into:

```
#Django code

aerial_size_dist = forms.ChoiceField(initial='Very Fine to Fine') 

#Translated HTML  
<tr><th><label for="id_aerial_size_dist">Aerial size dist:</label></th><td><select name="aerial_size_dist" id="id_aerial_size_dist"></select></td></tr>
```

My question is that how to add a label property such as "style" from working from the Django side? Can widget change Django form label property?

## Target HTML

```
<tr><th><label for="id_aerial_size_dist" style="display:none;">Aerial size dist:</label></th><td><select name="aerial_size_dist" id="id_aerial_size_dist"></select></td></tr>
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/ yes you can

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Similar problem is answered here: 
[Get the ID of a field widget in a formset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520536/get-the-id-of-a-field-widget-in-a-formset) .
Although it doesn't allow you to customize the ID directly, it uses default (autogenerated) ID

(Short answer) use this in template:

**EDIT:**

```
<label for="{{ form.my_field.id_for_label }}">{{ form.my_field.label }}</label>
```

---

**old one:** (this was not working in some cases - see comments)

```
<label for="{{ form.my_field.auto_id }}">{{ form.my_field.label }}</label>
```

Comment: The correct way to get an id for a label is with form.id_for_label. The difference is subtle but using auto_id causes a bug with MultiValueField+MultiWidget.

Answer (score 1):

```
class FormName(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FormName, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field_name'].widget.attrs['style'] = '...'
```

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried to add widget=forms.Select(attrs={'style':'display:none'}) to my code, but it only hide the drop down menu, not the label part. So my question is does Django have a form.label or similar stuff?